# Node.js SQL Server driver issue - How to troubleshoot

Tags: node.js, node-sqlserver

What is the correct way to troubleshoot this error with Node.js on Windows with the SQL Server driver.

events.js:2549: Uncaught Error: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0
]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error

- It is not the SQL statement - it works in other tools - like .NET
- Doesn't seem to be the SQL connection info - it works in other tools - like .NET

Any thoughts? What is the correct way for completely uninstalling node.js and starting over. I don't think my last install removed all my global modules.

```
var sql = require('node-sqlserver');
var _ = require('underscore')._;

var connstr = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost;" +
            "Initial Catalog=CDDB;Trusted_Connection={Yes}";

sql.open(connstr, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error opening the connection");
        return;
    } else {
        var stmt = "select top 10 * from Client";
        conn.query(connstr, stmt, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error running query!");
                return;
            }
            _.each(results, function (row) {
                console.log(row[0]);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First idea : Are users which runs your node.exe process and the one defined on your application pool - or maybe your current user account if you are using VS.NET to check your code are the same  ?

To troubleshoot :
I would use node-inspector - it allows to set up breakpoints onto your node.js code

To install it :
npm install -g node-inspector

To run it :
node --debug your-nodeapp-file.js

Launch another command line and run the following program :
node-inspector

Sorry but i do not have SQL Server to try your code, hope this help anyway.